# System-Level Network Security (Packet Classification and etc.) - SELinux and Libnftnl

Tags: network, linux, iptables, centos, selinux

I read that Libnftnl is a userspace library providing a low-level netlink programming interface to the in-kernel nf_tables subsystem and it uses NFTables.

Since it's a kernel related topic, at the very first time of hearing it the only thing sprang to my mind was SELinux whilst we can use it to manage our networking security solutions such as Labeled Networking (Labeling Packets passing between machines over the Network) amongst all other options it provides.

So is it something same as what we can do via SELinux or it is different? If not so, does anyone know why we may be in need of using NFTables and Libnftnl? Do we need it at all?

Answer (score 1):

Any form of network labeling for remote connections requires a robust Authentication system: SELinux uses IPSEC to achieve this;
though you can apply IPSEC without SELinux and local port labeling without IPSEC.... what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve Port Labeling with or without IPSec.